# How to Create TabItems without hidding flyouts WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

My Problem is that i have a windows in which indefine a Flyout, my tabControl and TabItems, but when I add a tabItem in Codebehind, the Flyout when selected the new tab doesnt show properly, it shows under the tab content
I have the following xaml

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Something.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Something.Views"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomethingUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000"
                  RightWindowCommandsOverlayBehavior="Never"
                  ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
                  GlowBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:Flyout IsPinned="False" Position="Right" Width="300" AreAnimationsEnabled="True" Header="Settings" IsOpen="{Binding IsSettingsFlyoutOpen,Mode=TwoWay}" >
            <views:Settings x:Name="settingsViewModel"></views:Settings>
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>


<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"
                Content="Settings"
                ToolTip="Settings" />
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Controls:MetroTabControl Name="tabCtrl">
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Busqueda">
            <views:Busqueda Margin="10"></views:Busqueda>
        </Controls:MetroTabItem>
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Playlists">
            <views:Playlists Margin="10"></views:Playlists>
        </Controls:MetroTabItem>
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Downloads">
            <views:Download Margin="10"></views:Download>
        </Controls:MetroTabItem>
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Biblioteca">
            <views:Biblioteca Margin="10" x:Name="bibliotecaView"></views:Biblioteca>
        </Controls:MetroTabItem>
        <Controls:MetroTabItem Header="Reproductor" >
            <views:Reproductor x:Name="reproductorView" Margin="0,10"></views:Reproductor>
        </Controls:MetroTabItem>
    </Controls:MetroTabControl>
    <views:MiniRep Grid.Row="1" x:Name="miniRepView"></views:MiniRep>
</Grid>
```

when I add a TabItem in codebehind

```
var ctrl = new Streaming(videoItem.id.watch);
        var tabCtrl = MainWindow.Instance.GetTab();
        tabCtrl.Items.Add(new MetroTabItem { Header = "Streaming", CloseButtonEnabled = true, Content = ctrl  });
```

the flyouts is below the tab
[Image Flyout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsYR9.png)

How can i create the tab below the flyout?

Comment: Which control is Streaming? If this a web browser or WinFormsHost then you should use the AirspaceDecorator from Microsoft.DwayneNeed https://microsoftdwayneneed.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks @punker76 the problem was in fact the WebBroser and not the ItemTab